# Error while creating a IAM Managed Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ASG",
            "Action": [
                "autoscaling:ResumeProcesses",
                "autoscaling:SuspendProcesses",
                "autoscaling:UpdateAutoScalingGroup"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                {
                    "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:autoscaling:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:*:*/*}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

In the above policy document, I get * not allowed error. How do I remove "*". If I remove all of them, It says resources cannot be empty.

Answer (score 0):

In the CloudWatch logs, please try to provide the region instead of the *.

Take an example from:
arn:aws:logs:region:*:*

You can view all the syntax that allowed per resource here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"Resource": "*"
```

You can do this for both `logs` and `autoscaling`.